# $\langle \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1\}, *\rangle$ isomorphic to $\langle \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\},\cdot\rangle$

Tags: group-theory

Let $\langle \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1\}, *\rangle$ be a group under the operation: $a*b= a+b+ab$. How to show that it is isomorphic to $\langle \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\},\cdot\rangle$ where $\cdot$ is the usual multiplication. Instead of defining some particular isomorphism is there any other method too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Calculate $(a+1)(b+1)$.

> Then we have $a*b\ +1 = (a+1)(b+1)$, so $\ x\mapsto x+1\ $ will be a homorphism $(\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\},*)\to (\Bbb R\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$, which clearly has an inverse.

And, usually the clearest thing  is indeed to define a particular isomorphism.

Comment: @akansha: If you find Berci's answer useful, you can upvote it (click the up arrow on the left of the answer). Furthermore, if you feel that it has completely answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the tick to the left of the answer. I am letting you know this as you haven't accepted any of the answers to your questions. You can find more information about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @akansha: You may want to go through the answers to your previous questions and see if there are any worth upvoting and/or accepting.